# Read Directly from the Event Store Or Implement a Copy of the Events in the Read Side

Tags: mongodb, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'am wokring on a project where I have implemented CQRS without event sourcing. I am using Mongo for the read database and also for the write database. When something has to be changed it is first changed in the write db and then the read db is synchronized.

Later I introtoduced somehting like Event Store, also a MongoDB instace. I am making history of all the events that changed the other databases in some way. The read db does not synchronize with the Event Store, so I have no way to read the events.

**I've reached a situation where I need the information that's inside the events from the Event Store. Should I connect directly to the Event Store and read from there or I should make the read db synchronize with the Event Store and basically hold a duplicate of the Event Store?**

Thank you in advance guys! I am using C# .NET Core if someone needs this kind of info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no functional reason why you shouldn't just read events directly from the event store.

The motivation for read models is usually low latency queries; we take the representation of data in the book of record (the event streams), and reshape it into a data structure that can answer queries.  We accept the consequences of eventual consistency to get fast response times.

But if the shape we need for a query is an event stream, then we can just use the source data.

If the queries of the event store are having a negative performance impact on the writes to the store, then we might redesign the system to direct queries to a cached copy of the events instead.

Comment: I agree on that, but if I need to modify these events before presenting them to the user it would be fine to hold a modofied copy in the read db. This way I will be making my JOINs when the read db is syncronizing and therefore I will have better read performance.

Comment: And also, disk space is cheap so it shouln't be a problem to hold a copy of the events. Basically, I think that there are 2 options: 1. Less required space but more read time (perform joins) or 2. More space, less read time (as joins are done on read db sync).

By join I mean resolve the ID fields.